# Channel Entries - searching relationship field?

Tags: channel-entries, relationships, grid, related-entries, reverse-related-entries

SEE: [Channel Entries - possible to search relationship field?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1051/channel-entries-possible-to-search-relationship-field)

**Has anything changed since the above question?** I want to list all Channel entries for a given value in a relationship field. Something like this:

`search:my_relationship:url_title="foo"`

**EDIT 1:**

I didn't explain my problem properly. My Channel has a grid. The grid has a relationship field. When I loop through the grid entries, I want to apply a search filter to it.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy using [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search) and its [Relationships filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#relationships). You don't necessarily need a search form, as you can use the [Results tag](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags#results-tag) as a drop-in replacement for the channel:entries tag. Then you can use this parameter:

```
{exp:low_search:results child:rel_field="1|2|3"}
```

...which will give you all entries that have entry ID 1, 2 or 3 assigned to them as a child.

Or:

```
{exp:low_search:results child:rel_field="foo"}
```

...which will give you all entries that has the entry with URL-title 'foo' assigned to them as a child.

The reverse is also possible:

```
{exp:low_search:results parent:rel_field="4|5|6"}
{exp:low_search:results parent:rel_field="bar"}
```

Comment: Thanks. I failed to mention that I am trying to loop the entries in a grid. One of the fields in the grid is a relationship field. I only want grid entries whose relationship field's url title matches a certain string. Is that possible with Low Search?