# low_search Field Grid and a relationship inside a column of the grid

Tags: relationships, search, low-search, grid, fields

I saw a similar question from 5 years ago, but I stumble upon the same question concerning low_search and combination with grid field and inside a column with a relationshipship.

Does low_search allow for a combination search of the two?
I presume it would have syntax like this:
search:fieldname_of_grid:child:columnname_in_grid

Does anyone have a lead how to manage a search like this?

The question from 2015:
[Channel Entries - searching relationship field?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/30903/channel-entries-searching-relationship-field)

Or do I need to write a custom filter for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was in the documentation all along:
https://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#relationships

The correct filter syntax you can use to search for relationship field inside a grid:
child:grid_field_name:column_name_insidegrid